# How can I run browserify-ed app in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify, amd

This may sound a little perverse, but I would like to adapt part of a pretty large JavaScript codebase so that it can be run on NodeJS. The code is written in the CommonJS style, with a `gulp` build process that uses `browserify` and `deamdify`. I didn't set any of this stuff up, and I'm only passingly familiar with the AMD vs CommonJS patterns.

I want to do this in order to convert some of the code to a server-side API, for performance - but it still needs to be able to run in the browser.

At first I thought I could simply use the libraries without running browserify, but I run into errors like this:

> ReferenceError: define is not defined

because some of the libraries are written like this:

```
/*global define*/
define([
        './defaultValue'
    ], function(
        defaultValue) {
    "use strict";
```

So it looks like I need to run `deamdify`, which is a browserify transform...hence I need to run browserify?

However, one downside of that seems to be that it generates a monolithic `Javascript` file (of course), which is then all parsed, and fails because it contains references to browser objects (`document.location`) which don't exist. I was hoping to just not use the bits of code that refer to browser objects.

So my questions:

> 1. Is there any guidance on how to proceed? Any tutorials? I couldn't find much on Google, but I may well be using the wrong terms.
> 2. Is there a NodeJS equivalent to Browserify? It seems a bit weird and unnecessary to build a monolithic Javascript file and then run
>    that server-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Using a (large) browser code base inside node can be challenging. I guess creating an environment module that provides a fake browser environment for node could do the job, this could be a lot of work though, you would have to change every browser environment reference to `window` etc. with a reference to the environment module. There you could decide in which environment the code is running and provide the appropriate behavior (e.g returning the `window` object in browsers and something different in a node environment).
2. First off: browserify is a library that runs on top of nodejs, so the "NodeJS equivalent to Browserify" makes no sense... as for avoiding the single javascript file: there are node modules that enable you to use AMD modules in node (e.g. [amdrequire](https://github.com/arqex/amdrequire), [node-amd-loader](https://github.com/ajaxorg/node-amd-loader)), maybe that could help. Another way is to convert the AMD modules to node modules - it depends on the amount of AMD modules.